# Recording to virtual disk

Tags: recording, virtual-disk

Is there any other software which create recording virtual disk?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://www.howtogeek.com/reviews/virtual-cd-version-10/

Answer (score 1):

It depends exactly what you want to do.

If you have a bunch of files and you simply want to put them in to an ISO file, the lightest and fastest solution would be [ISO Recorder](http://www.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm).

Other alternatives are [IMGBurn](http://www.imgburn.com) and [CDBurnerXP](http://www.cdburnerxp.se) which are both available through [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) for quick installation.